# How to configure moc options

Tags: qt, cmake, moc

I have CMake-based Qt5 project with precompiled headers (Common.h). `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` is OFF. I call `qt5_wrap_cpp` to generate moc_*.cpp files.

How I can configure moc, so it will add a custom include into generated moc_*.cpp files? (#include "Common.h")

Currently I use /FI compiler flag to force include of Common.h, but it is not friendly to code autocomplete tool (ReSharper).

"Common.h":

```
#ifdef QT_CORE_LIB
# include <QtCore>
#endif

#ifdef QT_GUI_LIB
# include <QtGui>
#endif

#ifdef QT_WIDGETS_LIB
# include <QtWidgets>
#endif

#ifdef QT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB
# include <QtMultimedia>
#endif

#ifdef QT_NETWORK_LIB
# include <QtNetwork>
#endif

#ifdef QT_XML_LIB
# include <QtXml>
#endif

#ifdef QT_QML_LIB
# include <QtQml>
#endif

#ifdef QT_QUICK_LIB
# include <QtQuick>
#endif

#ifdef QT_SQL_LIB
# include <QtSql>
#endif
```

Comment: It seems that moc does not provide some command line arg to do what you want. So what about to do this manually? For example with file(append ... ) ? http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html

Comment: @Chernobyl, It is equivalent of writing my own `qt5_wrap_cpp` function. Manual processing should be done after `moc`generation but before compilation. I'm no sure, how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never have to do that.

Moc can generate code from either an interface file (`.h`) or an implementation file (`.cpp`). In the first case, the interface itself is included at the beginning of the moc output. The `#include "Common.h"` belongs in your header, not in moc output. In the latter case, the moc output must be included by you at the end of the implementation file. And again, the `#include "Common.h"` belongs somewhere in your implementation file.

If you start thinking of what might necessitate inclusion of a header in moc output generate from an interface file, there's only one conclusion: you only need it if the *users of your interface* need that inclusion anyway. It is *never* moc's job to add such an inclusion for you.

Comment: I agree that it is not a moc job. I just need a workaround to improve usability of msvc + ReSharper. There are no problems with design / interfaces / compilation. Anyway, I don't think that it is good idea to include "Common.h" in header, because it is heavy. Event if it's requed. "Common.h" contains all Qt / STL includes.

Comment: Btw, including of "Common.h" is a requirement for all source (not header) files in whole project. So it is OK to use /FI compiler flag and to not include "Common.h" directly.

Comment: @SaZ Why would resharper need access to moc implementations? You'd be better off hiding mod-generated files from it. They don't help in any way.

Comment: To do correct introspection of Qt sources. Sometimes I need to debug throught generated files / Qt sources.

Comment: @SaZ But moc only provides implementations, everything is already fully declared...

Comment: Declared - yes. Resolving types from headers - no. Reason is upper.

Comment: @SaZ Your issue is not with resharper nor with moc. You don't have valid stand-alone headers. You need to revise the coding guidelines for your project to fix that - once you do, everything will fall in place. Oh, and Resharper C++ has a bug, too - you've provided a nice test case to show that it is so :)

Comment: Finally, I don't need to adjust moc generation, because it is a confirmed bug in resharper. There are everything ok with guidelines, I just wanted a temporary hack for R++ :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not related to CMake.

I created an issue in R++ bugtracker: [RSCPP-14920](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-14920)